# Display Android SDK Manager, Android Virtual Device manager buttons in eclipse?

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I have the ADT plug-in installed for Eclipse, but somehow the "Android SDK Manager" and "Android Virtual Device Manager" icons are hidden under "Windows" drop-down menu, instead of showing up in the toolbar besides "Save" and "Save As" in Eclipse. How can I set it so that they show up in the tool bar.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:
window->customize perspective->command groups availability->andriod and avd managers (CHECK this option)
and then Tool bar visibility->andriod and avd managers(CHECK this option)

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: I have eclipse 4.3 Kepler

Comment: your hope comes true ... thks

Comment: For Eclipse 4.5.1 it's Window\Perspective\Customize perspective\, and then in the Action Set Availability tab I had to check "Android SDK and AVD Manager"